# function composition meaning when functions are algebraic objects?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, function-and-relation-composition

I am reading a paper about persistent homology and was wondering if anyone knows what the meaning of function composition, $\circ$, is in this context?

> The persistent module, $M$, is the algebraic object of interest in
>   TDA. It consists of vector space $M_a$ for $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and
>   linear maps $M(a \le b): M_a \rightarrow M_b$ for all $a \le b$ such
>   that $M(a \le a)$ is the identify map so that for all $a \le b \le c$
>   it is that $M(b \le c) \circ M(a \le b) = M(a \le c)$.

Comment: It's right there in the quote: $M(a \le b)$ are linear maps, so composition means composition of linear maps.

Comment: So this would that be $M(b \le c) \circ M(a \le b) = M(M(a \le b) \le c) = M(a \le b \le c) = M(a \le c)$? Excuse my illiteracy of the notations, I'm only familiar with the function composition from regular functions.

Comment: These *are* just regular functions. $M(a \le b)$ is literally just a name for a linear map. Maybe the parentheses are throwing you off; would $M_{a \le b}$ make more sense to you? $a$ and $b$ are not the inputs, they are just part of the name of the function.

Comment: Yes, exactly! It was the parentheses throwing me off. That made much more sense to me. Thanks alot!